# How to listen to multiple queues simultaneously on same queue manager?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I want to listen to multiple (2) queues on the same queue manager from my spring boot (kotlin) app. I have the following MQ connection factory but not sure how to add the listeners for my 2 queues.

```
@Configuration
open class MqConfig {
    @Value("\${jms.mq.port}")
    private var port: Int = 0

    @Value("\${jms.mq.channel}")
    private var channel: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mq.host}")
    private var host: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mq.manager}")
    private var queueManager: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mqA.queue}")
    private var jmsMqA: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mqB.queue}")
    private var jmsMqB: String? = null

    @Bean
    open fun jmsMQConnectionFactory(): MQQueueConnectionFactory {
        val mqQueueConnectionFactory = MQQueueConnectionFactory()
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.port = port
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.channel = channel
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.hostName = host
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.queueManager = queueManager
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.transportType = WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT;
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketfactory;
    }
```

As you can see in the code above, the two queues I want to listen to are `jmsMqA` and `jmsMqB` but not sure where/how to use them.

I am new to queues and MQ, so if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to implement a listener and (possibly) publisher for those 2 queues, that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JmsListener` to listen the queues. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) is the link.

For example:

```
@Component
class QueueAListener {

    @JmsListener(
        destination = "\${jms.mqA.queue}",
        containerFactory = "jmsMQContainerFactory"
    )
    fun onMessage(message: Message) {
         // yours logic
    }
}
```

For queue B you can create new component or add method to the same class(don't forget to change method name).

UPD:

Container factory:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsMQContainerFactory")
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

You can use 'JmsTemplate' to send messages to queues. Please, check this [manual](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/)

Comment: And how to publish to those two queues?

Comment: Not working. Getting this exception: `Bean named 'jmsMQConnectionFactory' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory' but was actually of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory'`

Comment: Well, I've made a mistake, there should be a container factory. It means that you should create a 'DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory' for example. Usually, [ibmmq](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring) starter have an autoconfiguration, and you only fill the property file.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer is based on the sample in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Spring-JMS/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/samples/jms/spring/level114

Your `jmsMQConnectionFactory` bean should look something like (this is java)

```java
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.handlers.OurDestinationResolver;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.handlers.OurMessageConverter;
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConfigurationProperties;
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryFactory;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.QosSettings;


import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.JMSException;

@Configuration
public class MQConfiguration114 {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Bean
    public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        MQConfigurationProperties properties = new MQConfigurationProperties();
        // Properties will be a mix of defaults, and those found in application.properties
        // under ibm.mq
        // Here we can override any of the properties should we need to
        MQConnectionFactoryFactory mqcff = new MQConnectionFactoryFactory(properties,null);
        MQConnectionFactory mqcf = mqcff.createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);
        return mqcf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myContainerFactory114() throws JMSException {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory());

        // ... any customisations go here

        return factory;
    }


    // If you are going to be sending messages then
    @Bean("myJmsTemplate114")
    public JmsTemplate myJmsTemplate114() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(mqConnectionFactory());
        
        // .. Any customisations go here

        return jmsTemplate;
    }


}
```

Your listener code would look something like:

```java
package com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.level114;

import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.data.OurData;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

//@Component
public class MessageConsumer114 {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name1}", containerFactory = "myContainerFactory114")
    public void receiveRequest(OurData message) {
        logger.info("");
        logger.info( this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Received message of type: " + message.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Received message :" + message);
    }
}


    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name2}", containerFactory = "myContainerFactory114")
    public void receiveRequest(OurData message) {
        logger.info("");
        logger.info( this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Received message of type: " + message.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Received message :" + message);
    }
}
```

Your sender logic would look like:

```java
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.data.OurData;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.handlers.OurMessageConverter;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


//@Service
public class SendMessageService114 {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Value("${queue.name1}")
    public String sendQueue1;

    @Value("${queue.name2}")
    public String sendQueue2;

    final private JmsTemplate myJmsTemplate114;

    final private OurMessageConverter ourConverter = new OurMessageConverter();

    SendMessageService114(JmsTemplate myJmsTemplate114) {
        this.myJmsTemplate114 = myJmsTemplate114;
    }

    public void send1(OurData msg) {
        logger.info("Sending Message");
        myJmsTemplate114.convertAndSend(sendQueue1, msg);
    }

    public void send2(OurData msg) {
        logger.info("Sending Message");
        myJmsTemplate114.convertAndSend(sendQueue2, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I use the same `JmsListenerContainerFactory` bean to listen to both queues? And how to publish to those queues?

Comment: Answer has been updated with sender examples.

Comment: Getting this error: `o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxxxxxxxxx' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSCC1112: The operation for a domain specific object was not valid. The operation 'createTopic' is not valid for type 'QueueSession'.`